# cut grep and sort and printing out the value from textfile

Tags: bash, shell

I have a textfile which contains that following information

info.txt

```
1,susan,12345678,partTimeStaff,1
2,john,54243214,fullTimeStaff,3
3,mary,53214567,contractStaff,3
4,gerald,14546752,partTimeStaff,0
5,joe,14234567,fullTimeStaff,2
6,joshua,11234567,contractStaff,2
```

I am trying to get both the name of the staff and the number of working experience and print it out something like ("staffName total years of work experience: WorkExperience")

here's what I have currently

```
printOutName=$(cat "info.txt" | cut -d, -f2,4,5 | sort -r -t, -k2 | grep "partTimeStaff" | cut -d, -f1)
printOutYOfExp=$(cat "info.txt" | cut -d, -f2,4,5 | sort -r -t, -k2 | grep "partTimeStaff" | cut -d, -f3)

echo "part Time Staff"
echo -e "$printOutName total years of work experience: $printOutYOfExp"
```

I noticed that there's is a problem with the output shown below
output

```
part Time Staff
gerald 
susan  total years of work experience : 0
1
```

expected output

```
part Time Staff
gerald total years of work experience : 0
susan  total years of work experience : 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that loops finds each category name and generates the desired output for each of them. I have put it in a function so you can call it directly:

EDIT 2: Made it shorter!

```
countstaff(){
    TYPE=$(cut -d, -f4 info.txt | sort -u )
    for T in $TYPE; do 
        echo "--- $T ---"
        printf "%s total years of work experience: %s\n" $(grep ${T} info.txt | cut -d, -f2,5 | tr ',' ' ')
    done
    }
```

Output:

```
--- contractStaff ---
mary total years of work experience: 3
joshua total years of work experience: 2
--- fullTimeStaff ---
john total years of work experience: 3
joe total years of work experience: 2
--- partTimeStaff ---
susan total years of work experience: 1
gerald total years of work experience: 0
```

**EDIT:** In response to peer pressure `<coff @gniourf_gniourf coff/>` I have streamlined the function a bit, although making a slightly less flexible on the file format (the `sed` has to match input fields more precisely). Output is as above (with indentation on the subheads):

```
countstaff(){
    FILEN="info.txt"  # can change this to "$1" to change file at run time
    TYPE=$(cut -d, -f4 "$FILEN" | sort | uniq)
    for T in $TYPE; do 
        echo "--- $T ---"
        printf "  %s - worked days: %s\n" $(grep "$T" "$FILEN" | sed -E 's/^[0-9]+,([A-Za-z]+).*,([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/g')
    done
}
```

Comment: Exercise 1: count the number of subshells spawned, divide by the number of lines and compare with 0.5. Bonus question: do you think it is a good method?

Comment: Subshells don't cost anything, at least on my system... My metric for good is something that can be edited and is understandable and does the job robustly. Your one-liner is nice too.

Comment: ok @gniourf_gniourf I spent some time on a more efficient solution!

Comment: `sort | uniq` would be better written as `sort -u` if your `sort` happen to be smart enough to possess the `-u` switch. And that's a shame that `mary ann`, `billie-joe` or `désirée` can't be part of the staff! `:)`

Comment: Oh, and piping `grep` through `sed` is usually not the best option!

Comment: All true, but ... I have a job I am supposed to be doing, and it's not refining S.O. answers. ;^) The OP can take it from here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk` for this task as it is good for processing delimited data.

```
$ awk -F, '/partTimeStaff/{print $2" total years of work experience : "$5}' info.txt
susan total years of work experience : 1
gerald total years of work experience : 0
```

Comment: Notice that if a guy's name contains `partTimeStaff`, you'll have some surprises. Ok, I don't know anyone with such a name, but who knows?

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the file line by line, put each field in array fields, select the lines you want, and output the formated fields, as in:

```
echo "part Time Staff"
while IFS=, read -r -a array; do
    [[ "${array[3]}" == partTimeStaff ]] || continue
    printf "%s total years of work experience: %s\n" "${array[1]}" "${array[4]}"
done < info.txt
```

and it's all 100% bash, no external tools, and no subshells!

Answer (score 2):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print "$F[1] total years of work experience: $F[4]" if $F[3] eq "partTimeStaff"' info.txt
susan total years of work experience: 1
gerald total years of work experience: 0
```

Comment: Yes. Perl is part of LSB so should be portable enough and it was designed exactly for that!

Comment: hanks alot for your advice and help

Answer (score 2):

And just for fun:

```
( IFS=$'\n,'; printf '%.0s%s total years of work experience:%.0s%.0s %s\n' $(grep 'partTimeStaff' info.txt ) )
```

Comment: The `%.0s` is clever. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Happy you enjoy my fun solution `:)`